# Where to make the class handle entity (like entity wrapper)

Tags: php, symfony

I want to know where should I put new class on symfony2.

What the class I want to make the class which control entities.

For example I have entity like this

item

```
id shop item price 
1  A    shoes 20
2  B    shoes 30
3  A    hat   10
4  A    shirt 20
5  C    egg   40
6  B    hat   20
```

in this case, I have `Item.php` under /Entity directory.

And adding some functions like setter/getter to Item.php.

Each function can control one row.

However I want to have some methods which could control multiple rows.
like `getAllSumPrice()`, `getMostCheapItem()` and so on. (Of corse you can do it by SQL but I would like to do more complex control.)

Where should I put this new class?? under `Entity`?? `Controller`? `Command`?

I need to make new service and injection???

Comment: This kind of class is usually called a Service.

Comment: I would make a service, and inject doctrine or the item repository to make this calculations. Then call from the controller or from another service. Hope it helps. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a [custom Repository Class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the repository
{YourBundle}/Repository/ItemRepository.php

so on the controller when you call the Item Repository you can use that functions.